# Angular 7 - Efficient way to design components for a desktop chat interface?

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, frontend, chat

I need to develop a desktop chat interface just like LinkedIn.

[image]

I am thinking to create a parent container component which will have 3 child components as shown in the screenshot.

Component 1 will have the list of chat user list.

Component 2 will have a list of all the messages for the selected user/group and a send-message form at the bottom.

Component 3 will have the details about the selected user/group like shared media, tags, group name, group image.

Component 2 and Component 3 will subscribe to list-item click of Component 1. So whenever a user/group is clicked from Component 1, all the details of that specific user/group will be populated in Component 2 and 3.

Similarly, each sibling can communicate with other 2 components and update each other's data as needed. For example, if user sends a photo from message form in Component 2, then Component 1 and Component 3 will get updated accordingly.

All the three component would be siblings and the router path will be given to the parent container which hold all these 3 components.

Is this a right approach to design such interface using Angular 7?

Comment: To me, your approach sounds ok. Happy coding..!!!

Comment: According to me your approach is right.

Comment: Yes ! This absolutely right to start with...happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

I designed something similar, though smaller as it only had two panels, not three:

[image]

I used two child components:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <pm-product-shell-list></pm-product-shell-list>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-8'>
        <pm-product-shell-detail></pm-product-shell-detail>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could add a third one similarly.

However, instead of attempting to have the components communicate directly, I set up a service. Each component subscribed to that service to receive change notifications.

So if a user picked an item from the list on the left, it would communicate with the service that the selected product was changed. The other component would then receive notification from the service that a change occurred so it could react accordingly (again, this would work with a third component as well.)

This makes the system much less coupled and easier to modify and maintain.

I've implemented this three different ways:

**1) Using a simple service with BehaviorSubject.** 
Code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Communication/tree/master/APM-Final

This is a snippet of the service:

```
private selectedProductSource = new BehaviorSubject<IProduct | null>(null);
selectedProductChanges$ = this.selectedProductSource.asObservable();

changeSelectedProduct(selectedProduct: IProduct | null): void {
    this.selectedProductSource.next(selectedProduct);
}
```

The list component:

```
  onSelected(product: IProduct): void {
    this.productService.changeSelectedProduct(product);
  }
```

The detail component (where the template was bound to `product`):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.productService.selectedProductChanges$.subscribe(
        selectedProduct => this.product = selectedProduct
    );
}
```

**2) Using a simple service with getters.**
Code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Communication/tree/master/APM-FinalWithGetters

The service (a simple property):

```
currentProduct: IProduct;
```

The list component:

```
  onSelected(product: IProduct): void {
    this.productService.currentProduct = product;
  }
```

The detail component (where the template was bound to `product`):

```
get product(): IProduct | null {
    return this.productService.currentProduct;
}
```

**3) Using NgRx for state management.**
Code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-NgRx-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Demo4